# How to get count of Each Item when using WHERE IN without Subquery

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table comment
[image]

`SELECT * FROM comment WHERE coupon_id IN (28,14,56);`

I want to select all comments and total number of comments for each coupon *[coupon ID's are (28,14,56) ]*

Please check the [SQLFiddle Showing the Query](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5b1f6/3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to select total number of comments for each coupon [coupon ID's are (28,14,56) ]

You need to use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT
    coupon_id,
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    comment
WHERE
    coupon_id IN (28,14,56)
GROUP BY
    coupon_id;
```

If you want to get the number of comments together with all the comments, you'll have to use a subquery:

```
SELECT 
    *,
    (SELECT 
           COUNT(*) 
     FROM 
          `comment` AS cnt_comment 
     WHERE 
          cnt_comment.coupon_id=comment.coupon_id
    ) AS total_comments
FROM 
     `comment` 
WHERE 
     coupon_id IN (28,14);
```

[sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5b1f6/7)

Comment: Thanks. I tried with SUBQUERY, But Missed `GROUP BY`. This is SImpler than Subquery

Comment: Oh there is an Issue, I want all the comment (Now it is showing one comment only) [Screenshot of Query](http://i.imgur.com/7jOKsN8.png)

Comment: @abdulrashid Please, provide sample data into sqlfiddle. So I could reproduce the issue. Where is it showing only 1 comment? This query shouldn't show any comments, only number of comments per coupon_id.

Comment: I added it to Question. It may help others

Comment: @abdulrashid If you want to get all the records from the table and get the count in each row, there is no other option but subquery.

Answer (score 1):

Use `GROUP BY`. Try with -

```
SELECT 
    *, COUNT(comment_id) AS total_comment 
FROM comment 
WHERE coupon_id IN (28,14,56) 
GROUP BY coupon_id
```

Remove `*` if you dont want all the columns and specify the needed one.

Comment: why select all instead of coupon_id?

Comment: @Prashant it depends on the situation. if all the rows needed then it will be there elese simply remove it. And the OP is using it also.